# Change price template only for product view page?

Tags: magento2, price, template

as far as I understand this the price is rendered in:

[/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml)

But as I change it, it gets, of course, changed for every part of the site (like category view).

How can I change how my price is displayed in my product view? If I for example want to add labels for price incl. tax and excl. tax, tax amount, etc..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `catalog_product_view.xml` there is a block (`product.price.render.default`) which is responsible for price rendering.

That block you can find in below paths:

1. `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/CATALOG_PRODUCT_COMPOSITE_CONFIGURE.xml`
2. `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/layout/default.xml`

which is this:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.default">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="price_render_handle" xsi:type="string">catalog_product_prices</argument>
            <argument name="use_link_for_as_low_as" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            <!-- set "override" configuration settings here -->
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

You can copy this block to `catalog_product_view.xml` inside body tag and change this

`<argument name="price_render_handle" xsi:type="string">catalog_product_prices</argument>`

to this

`<argument name="price_render_handle" xsi:type="string">custom_catalog_product_prices</argument>`.

Then create a new xml layout file with name `custom_catalog_product_prices.xml`  and copy content from file `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml`.

After copy content you can see there is so many template set in this xml layout now you can modify templates according to you in `custom_catalog_product_prices.xml` file.

Comment: This does not seem to work, although I am unsure how i should add the template. Just like `template="Module_Vendor::product/price/amount/custom.phtml"` ?

Comment: i have updated my answer please check.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The only problem I encountert is that as soon as I add my custom_catalog_product_prices.xml adjustments like price excl. tax don't show up anymore.

Comment: there is one more catalog_product_prices.xml in Magento_Tax module, please explore and checke what changes you can append into your own.

Comment: this seems a long way from the usual "add template in correct location and hope for the best", I'm wondering why .. anyway thank you !

Comment: Agree with medmek's comment. Simply adding override files with the same names, into you own theme will do the trick. 
In my case, I wanted to change the order of the special and regular price blocks (without css, if possible) and change the 'Regular Price' label to 'Retail Price Was'.

To do this, I copied the 'vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml' to my theme, made the text and layout order updates I needed and voila, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem several times.  The client often wants a different price display based on where the customer is viewing a product.  Category page vs product detail page would be one example.

My solution is to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml` and place it in your own theme folder.

From there you can use block methods to retrieve the current layout handle using `$block->getRequest()->getFullActionName()` that will return a value based on the page you are viewing

- catalog_product_view (Product Detail Page)
- catalog_category_view (Category Listing)
- Just echo the handle for any other pages with prices to find others

You can then use the layout handle in an if statement and change display of the price based on layout handle

```
$handle = $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
if($handle == 'catalog_product_view') {
    //Product price display
} else {
    //Default price display
}
```