# Change price template only for product on product page and not for other sections like related products sections

Tags: magento2, page-layouts

I was able to change the price design for only product page using the solution in this link

[Change price template only for product view page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210585/change-price-template-only-for-product-view-page)

My code:
In catalog_product_view.xml file I have added this code in the body tag

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.default">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="price_render_handle" xsi:type="string">blanco_catalog_product_prices</argument>
            <argument name="use_link_for_as_low_as" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            <!-- set "override" configuration settings here -->
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

And I have created a new XML file blanco_catalog_product_prices.xml inside my custom module and here is the content.

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
            <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Custom_BlancoLayout::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

This is the line that is changed in the above file.

```
<item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Custom_BlancoLayout::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
```

Now the price is rendering from the above file for the main product,
[image]

but the price design for the other sections on the product page also changed. Like for related products.

[image]

I want to show the price in this style only for main product and not for other sections.
I could not think of any solution. Please suggest how I can achieve this. I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite easy, we can achieve this using CSS.
Add style only for the section where we want to show the price in different style and that's it.